# Vb.net send an xml to a web service

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap

I want to send an xml to a web service
xml looks like this

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
    <OTA_HotelRatePlanRQ Version="2.1" PrimaryLangID="en-us" TimeStamp="2001-12-17T09:30:47Z" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <POS>
    <Source>
    <RequestorID ID="aa" MessagePassword="bb" Type="cc">
    <CompanyName Code="C" CodeContext="dd"/>
    </RequestorID>
    </Source>
    </POS>
    </OTA_HotelRatePlanRQ>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

I know I can manually build the xml but is there a simple way?
For instance

the web service is called webs_test
So in vb.net I write

```
  Dim trip As New webs_test.OTA_HotelRatePlanRQ
  trip.POS.Source.RequestorID.ID = "aa"
  trip.POS.Source.RequestorID.MessagePassword = "bb"
  trip.POS.Source.RequestorID.Type = "cc"
  trip.POS.Source.RequestorID.CompanyName.Code = "C"
  trip.POS.Source.RequestorID.CompanyName.CodeContext = "dd"
```

from here is there a simple way to build the xml and send to the web service?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Supposing this service is at `http://someserver.com/Some.svc` and it exports a WSDL describing itself at `http://someserver.com/Some.svc?WSDL`, you right click yor solution explorer References node, you choose *Add Service reference* and you paste the WSDL URL in (or even the non WSDL URL; it's smart enough to try tacking ?WSDL on the end). Few clicks and naming choices later and you can write code which might look like:

```
Dim x as New SomeServiceNamespace.SomeClient()

x.GetRatePlan("aa", "bb", "cc", "C", "dd") 'method name comes from the WSDL
```

And it does the rest..

Incidentally, if the service doesn't describe itself it doesn't mean all is lost; some web service providers turn off WSDL generation by the service itself but they're willing to supply you the same WSDL the service *would* have sent, as an XML file. In this case, put it in e.g. `c:\temp` and in the *Add Service reference..* dialog, put `c:\temp\the_wsdl_filename.xml` in the address box

Comment: thx Caius, the problem is that we don't have the method GetRatePlan I just need to build an xml using the scheme coming from the WSDL. I wondered if there were an easy way from the wsdl to build it

Comment: The WSDL will describe the operations of the service, one of which is (should) be e.g. GetRatePlan or whatever

Answer (score 0):

I do it using Xml linq :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim soap As String = _
            "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" & _
                "<soap:Header/>" & _
                "<soap:Body>" & _
                    "<OTA_HotelRatePlanRQ Version=""2.1"" PrimaryLangID=""en-us"" TimeStamp=""2001-12-17T09:30:47Z"" xmlns=""http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"">" & _
                        "<POS>" & _
                            "<Source>" & _
                                "<RequestorID ID=""aa"" MessagePassword=""bb"" Type=""cc"">" & _
                                    "<CompanyName Code=""C"" CodeContext=""dd""/>" & _
                                "</RequestorID>" & _
                            "</Source>" & _
                        "</POS>" & _
                    "</OTA_HotelRatePlanRQ>" & _
                "</soap:Body>" & _
            "</soap:Envelope>"

        Dim envelope As XElement = XElement.Parse(soap)
        Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim id As String = "John"
        Dim password As String = "apple"
        Dim type As String = "123"
        Dim company = "XYZ"
        Dim codeContext = "STU"

        Dim ota As XElement = envelope.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "OTA_HotelRatePlanRQ").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim ns As XNamespace = ota.GetDefaultNamespace()
        ota.SetAttributeValue("TimeStamp", now.ToString("D"))

        Dim requestorID As XElement = ota.Descendants(ns + "RequestorID").FirstOrDefault()
        requestorID.SetAttributeValue("ID", id)
        requestorID.SetAttributeValue("MessagePassword", password)
        requestorID.SetAttributeValue("Type", type)

        Dim companyName As XElement = requestorID.Element(ns + "CompanyName")
        companyName.SetAttributeValue("Code", company)
        companyName.SetAttributeValue("CodeContext", codeContext)



    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thx Jd, I know I can use linq or xml writer, Just wondered if there were a simple way from the wsdl to build the xml

Comment: The WSDL is a schema.  so you would have to create c# or VB.Net classes from schema and then serialize. the classes.